# Only use before_filter once per individual user request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a mobile version of a site which on the home page load (`root_path`) will redirect to the mobile version if a mobile device is detected (`home_mobile_path`). I put a before filter on the home page action to check the device but I only want it to do the before filter once in order to allow the user to get to the home page (`root_path`) without always being redirected to the mobile version if they want to see the actual home page from a mobile device.

Could make another page and path just for that but that doesn't seem very d.r.y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store a flag in the `session` hash and make sure that the redirect only occurs once

```
unless session[:mobile_redirect]
  session[:mobile_redirect] = true
  redirect_to home_mobile_path
end
```